# JOOQ GenerationTool non-deterministic?

Tags: mysql, jooq

We are using JOOQ-generated Java classes to interact with our MySQL database. I've just noticed that the GenerationTool seems to be nondeterministic. I can see this being the result of MySQL returning things in unpredictable orders or because JOOQ isn't being explicit with some queries but wanted to see if anyone has run into this and has figured out a solution.

It's not really a huge problem because the generated classes continue to work as expected but it muddies up our github pull-requests which we use for code review.

Comment: In general, the order is explicit and enforced via `ORDER BY` clauses in dictionary view queries. But there may be bugs... What version of jOOQ are you using? What particular objects did you find to be "non-deterministic"?

Comment: We are at JOOQ v3.3.1. It seems to always create a new ...schema.Keys and then random collection of table and records classes. I've been able to run it on a clean git repo and it will generate some changed classes. Then git reset --hard and generate again and will sometimes get a different set of changes. schema.Keys is usually in there though.

Comment: OK, sorry for not trying this first but if I upgrade to 3.4.4 I can not reproduce this. As I said in my question, this isn't really causing a huge problem but if it does before we are ready to upgrade JOOQ, I'll know the solution.

Comment: @LukasEder, if you want to post "upgrade JOOQ" as an answer, I'll be happy to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably an issue that has been fixed along with [#3560](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3560), as the previous query to fetch key information might indeed have been non-deterministic with respect to the order of keys within a table.

I take from your comments, that upgrading to the latest version has fixed this issue for you (the above fix was included in [jOOQ 3.4.3](http://www.jooq.org/notes?version=3.4))